# Sending file to S3 from my server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

Here is my code which works if I run it locally but not if I run on my server to transfer my `csv` to `s3` using `PHP` from my server.

```
<?php

// Include the AWS SDK using the Composer autoloader.    
require 'vendor/autoload.php';    
use Aws\S3\S3Client;    
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;        
$s3 = new S3Client([   
 'version' => 'latest',    
 'region' => 'us-east-2'   
]);    
$bucket = 'edtopia';    
$keyname = 'sample_1.csv';                   
try {   
    // Upload data.    
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(    
        'Bucket' => $bucket,    
        'Key'    => $keyname,    
        'Body'   => fopen('numberclub.org/edtopiadb/df_corr.csv', 'r'),    
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'    
    ));
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";    
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";   
}
```

EDIT- This now working for me on the server, Now my challenge is to access the file on the local system to be sent to s3 using this php script where in the BODY i need to define my local system file path and this code running on the server. What is the effective way to achieve it

Comment: Do you have any logs from running on your server?

Comment: Is run this code without any error but doesn't echo the  $result['ObjectURL'] also the file do not get uploaded to csv. I suspect the use of use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception; if properly executed here or not

Comment: try to create the s3 client inside the try/catch, AND catch all exceptoins. Also test whether $s3 is null.

Comment: Same result unable to echo the result

Comment: How do i setup Aws\S3\S3Client on the siteground server ?

Comment: I need to send my csv to S3 using php from the server!

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Fatal error: Class 'S3Client' not found in /home/c10mill2/public_html/edtopiadb/filetoS3.php on line 21

Comment: Your error message means that the AWS PHP SDK is not installed on your EC2 instance (or not correctly setup). Note: if your PHP is running in a web server, then you cannot (should not) install the PHP SDK in your home directory. The SDK needs to be installed where the Apache or IIS service can access it.

Comment: How can I install aws php sdk on my siteground server?